# Finding explicit linear dependence relation when having infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have those vectors:
$(3,2,1)
,(0,1,2)
,(0,1,0)
,(-1,0,2)$

I have to find the explicit linear dependence relation.
So I've put the vectors as columns in a matrix and the solutions vector I got is:
$(\frac{1}{3}t,\frac{-7}{6}t,\frac{1}{2}t,t)$ when $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Now I'm not sure how to express the linear dependence relation.
Should I let t be a specific number that I choose and then just write the equation?
Should I write it as a span?

Comment: yes,take $t=6$ as I did below, e.g. This gives one of the infinitely many choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the given vectors as *columns* in a matrix because we need a vector $(x,y,z,t)$ such that

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
3&0&0&-1\\
2&1&1&0\\
1&2&0&2\\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

so we reduce $$\begin{bmatrix} 
3&0&0&-1\\
2&1&1&0\\
1&2&0&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$ to (say)

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0&0&-\frac13\\
0&2&2&\frac43\\
0&0&-2&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$ giving the parametrised solution (in the final variable $t$):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3}t\\ -\frac{7}{6}t\\ \frac{1}{2}t\\t\end{bmatrix}$$

as you also found, and take (to get round numbers) $t=6$ to get

$$2\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\\1 \end{bmatrix} -7 \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2 \end{bmatrix}
+3\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}+6\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\2 \end{bmatrix}$$

as an explicit proof of linear dependence.